# Internet Explorer Toolbar disappears on some web sites

Tags: internet-explorer-8, toolbar, internet-explorer-7

Internet Explorer Toolbar disappears on some web sites. Usually I can start normally but after clicking on a link that takes me to another part of their site, a new window opens with no toolbar. Hitting F11 doesn't change things. Its like the site doesn't want me to have those features. Does anyone know how to get the toolbars back on the pages? This is on IE7 and IE8.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a link?

Comment: I cant unfortunately, its behind a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature of JavaScript's `window.open([URL])`. It opens a page in a bare window.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Is there a way to get around it? My end game is to be able to scrape data from it, but I need access to the source.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with amphetamachine, it is a function of the website using a JavaScript command to open an instance of the browser without the toolbar displayed.

Have you tried doing a right-mouse button click on the page, to see if the context menu popup will show, so you can view the source that way?  (Of course it is possible, using JavaScript, to disable this functionality, too, but it is worth a shot.)